# Computer won't recognize Chrome as default browser after cleaned browers-hijack

Tags: windows-8, google-chrome, hijack

I recently had suspicions that my Chrome was hi-jacked and found out it had been. It was now something called "gunship", which I only managed to find ONE similar case of.

I deleted Gunship and cleaned my computer with MSE, malwarebytes and Hitman Pro, which found several instances of malware and other bad stuff.

Since I deleted Gunship (fake-chrome) I've been unable to open .url files and/or links via skype or other programs.

I looked in standard settings for apps in windows 8, and where the Chrome logo should be is a grey blank box or the "unknown program"-icon.

[Picture example 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6H4Qu.png)

[Picture example 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xVX5E.png)

I have also checked what chrome is set to in the registry and it seems to be the correct one.

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling Chrome?

Comment: @DavidPostill - Yep

Comment: try uninstalling chrome, restart, delete any leftovers, download the chrome installer and install again. as it might be a problem within your profile, you could check that so that you create an additional user (administrator profile) and try with that user. another solution which could work: install firefox, set it as default, close it, start chrome go to options and select set as default.

Comment: Can't read your screenshots

Comment: Download [FileTypeDiag](https://www.pretentiousname.com/miscsoft/) and generate a dump for .HTM file type. Upload this log (plain-text) to Pastebin.com and share us the link. This file would show what's wrong with the DP registration.

Comment: @w32sh - here's the pastebin dump http://pastebin.com/viVLix0G

Answer (score 0):

Try uninstalling chrome with Revo Uninstaller. Then use CCleaner to clean out leftovers in the registry. Reboot and reinstall chrome.

Answer (score 0):

Start Regedit.exe and go to:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\ChromeHTML
```

Export the key to a REG file.

Right-click `ChromeHTML` and choose Delete.

Exit Regedit.exe